# Is it possible to use an Ecmascript6 script out of an Ecmascript5 script without transpiling?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

I‘ve written some modules in Ecmascript6 for a system which is written in Ecmascript5. The modules are working properly as they should as well as  the rest of the system.

Is it know possible for the system to use these new modules without transpiling them back into ES5? This question is not meant to be for a specific project or setup, more like a general possiblity working with ES5 and ES6.

Thank's for the help.

Comment: If you're running the code in an environment that does support ES2015 (the correct name for what used to be called ES6) then the environment also supports ES5.  It's still all JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the platform you are going to run it. If your platform supports ES 2016, you won't have any problem running it.

Example: Chrome supports latest ECMA Script features, so all your ECMA 6 and ECMA 7 functions will run properly, While older Internet Explorer does not support ECMA 6. So you won't be able run your codes there.

So it doesn't matter if your module was earlier written in ECMA 2015 or ECMA 2016, All latest ECMA script versions are backward compatible. And that's the beauty of JavaScript.

Comment: Chrome supports some ECMAScript 2019 (or ES10?) features!

Comment: The latest version of Chrome now supports ES10.

Comment: That’s what I said...? ES10 isn’t a thing really. It’s just a nickname.

Comment: Oh sorry, Actually I got confused with the question mark in your statement :D

Comment: Ha! No problem.